# how to parse value to nested select in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to pass `parsed_param` to nested select. Like this .

```
select name ,ord.sq,ord.sp ,sandwich_id as parsed_param 
from sandwiches , (select sum(quantity) as sq, sum(total_price) as sp 
                   from order_sandwiches 
                   where sandwich_code=parsed_param) as ord

   order by parsed_param
```

Comment: So u want your sandwich_id to be rename to what ever parsed_param is? The order by will still remain sandwich_id, because order by is column identifier, not renamed column identifier.

Comment: -i want to iterate on the nested select by `parsed_param` . i don't know if it possible to make recursive iteration with mysql .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT sandwiches.name,
  sandwiches.sandwich_id,
  sum(order_sandwiches.quantity) as sq,
  sum(order_sandwiches.total_price) as sp
FROM sandwiches
JOIN order_sandwiches ON order_sandwiches.sandwich_code = sandwiches.sandwich_id
GROUP BY sandwiches.name, sandwiches.sandwich_id
ORDER BY sandwiches.sandwich_id
```

Comment: - get error . ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 

manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 

near 'JOIN
order_sandwiches ON order_sandwiches.sandwich_code = 

sandwiches.sandwich_id' at
line 5

Comment: -note 2 table description . 
sandwiches table (sandwich_id, name)  , order_sandwishes 

(quantity,total_price ,sandwich_id)

Comment: Sorry forgot to include FROM sandwiches, I modified the answer to reflect the changes